# How do i access the url variable defined in the Zend Framework config.ini

Tags: zend-framework, zend-config

```
[dev]
great.url="www.google.com"
[test : dev]
great.url="www.yahoo.com"
[prod : test]
great.url="www.aol.com"
```

I have my own functions which return the  Config of the environment that is used(DEV,TEST,OR PROD) .
Now my problem is  `$myclassinstance->getConfig()->great->url;` (when i say this it is returning url correctly in dev) 
where as in test it is returning notice "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in file test.php on line no 19" this error is coming  due to empty 
of this statement `($myclassinstance->getConfig()->great->url;)`.it is returning correctly in dev . What might be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be defaulting to dev. To fix it, you need to do something like this:

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini('/path/to/config.ini', 'prod');
$myclassinstance->setConfig($config);
```

or depending on how you have things setup:

```
$myclassinstance->config = $config;
```

Then your code should work:

```
$myclassinstance->getConfig()->great->url;
```

Documentation is here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.config.adapters.ini.html